# Codeigniter Как передать элементы из бд в тег `<option>`

Tags: php, html, html5, codeigniter

Как передать элементы из бд в тег `<option>`?

Вот код:

```
 <?php echo form_open('new_work'); ?>
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/codeIgniter-3.1.5/css/add.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="../js/safronov.js"> </script>




</head>
<body onload="cloNeN();changer(); cloNeN();changer();">

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">

      <div class="calend container-fluid">
      <p class="customer" id="ih">
         <input type="date" name="date" placeholder="Select date"  class="feedback-input"  id="date" />
      </p>

    </div>

  <div id="form-main" class="form-div col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" name="main">
  <div id="form-div">
    <form class="form" id="form1">

      <p class="customer" id="ih">
          <select style="background-image: url(/codeigniter-3.1.5/images/customer.png);  background-size: 30px 30px;  background-position: 11px 8px;  background-repeat: no-repeat;" type="text" name="Customer0" placeholder="Select customer"  class="feedback-input"  id="Customer"  >
          <option>Select customer</option>
          </select>
      </p>

      <p class="project">
          <select style="background-image: url(/codeigniter-3.1.5/images/project.png);  background-size: 30px 30px;  background-position: 11px 8px;  background-repeat: no-repeat;" type="text" name="Project0" placeholder="Select project"  class="feedback-input" id="Project" >
          <option>Select project</option>
          </select>
      </p>

     <p class="activity">
         <select style="background-image: url(/codeigniter-3.1.5/images/activity.png);  background-size: 30px 30px;  background-position: 11px 8px;  background-repeat: no-repeat;" type="text" name="Activity0" placeholder="Select activity"  class="feedback-input" id="Activity" >
         <option>Select activity</option>
         </select>
      </p>

        <p class="hours">
          <input style="background-image: url(/codeigniter-3.1.5/images/time.png);  background-size: 30px 30px;  background-position: 11px 8px;  background-repeat: no-repeat;" type="number" step="0.5" name="Hours0" placeholder="Hours" class="feedback-input" id="Hours" />
      </p>

        <p class="comment">
          <input style="background-image: url(/codeigniter-3.1.5/images/comment.png);  background-size: 30px 30px;  background-position: 11px 8px;  background-repeat: no-repeat;" type="textarea" name="Comment0" placeholder="You can type comment"  class="feedback-input" id="Comment"/>
      </p>
    </form>   
  </div>
</div>


        <div id="clone">
            </div>
                </div>

            <div class="buttons">
          <button type="button" id="button-green" onclick="document.getElementById('value').value +=1; cloNeN();changer();">Add Form</button>
          <button type="submit" id="button-blue">Add Work</button>
          <button type="button" id="button-red" onclick="remover()">Delete Form</button>
            </div>



    <script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script>
    $.backstretch(["../images/addwork.jpg"]);
    </script>
         <input type="hidden" name="value" value="111" id="value">
</body>
```

Comment: Через `while`:  select  `while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){<option></option>}` /select    к примеру...

Comment: В данном конкретном случае цикл наверное не подойдет, т.к. придется генерировать всю структуру формы. Будет проще вытащить весь массив строк и потом раскидать по тегам `<option>`. Но идея с цикл очень полезная. Согласен, что все данные должны формироваться динамически!

Comment: @Артёмыч ну все зависит от того, каким образом получаются данные из БД. С codeigniter не сталкивался - поэтому не могу судить.

Answer (score 2):

**Простой пример на `чистом PHP`**

```
<?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
?>
<p class="activity">
    <option><?=$row[0]?></option>
</p>
```

**Конкретно в вашем случае для `codeigniter`**

[Вот пример контроллера, который загружает модель, затем подает вид:](http://codeigniter3.info/guide/general/models)

```
class Blog_controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function blog()
    {
        $this->load->model('blog');

        $data['query'] = $this->blog->get_last_ten_entries();

        $this->load->view('blog', $data);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как это сделать именно в codeignitere , через модели и контроллеры?

Comment: С `codeignitere` не работал, но принцип практически у всех фреймворков одинаковы, вначале в `контроллере` получаем из `модели` данные потом передаем их в `вид`. Я обновил ответ.

Comment: Изучайте по шагам, вначале читаем как работать с контроллером http://codeigniter3.info/guide/general/controllers, потом разбираемся что такое модель http://codeigniter3.info/guide/general/models и уже после этого думаем как все это отобразить на виде http://codeigniter3.info/guide/general/views. Не всё так просто, но и не всё так сложно :)

Comment: Когда говорил про одинаковый принцип, имел в виду саму модель MVC!

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%">
    <?php if ( ! empty($countries) && is_array($countries)): ?>
         <?php foreach($countries AS $item): ?>
             <option ><?= $item['country_name']?></option>
         <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php endif ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Добавьте комментарии к Вашему ответу